# Can't align boxes to the same line

Tags: html, css

I can't align these two boxes to the same line, everytime i put some text on them they misalign. What am i doing wrong? Seems like it's something with the inline-block. Ignore the content please.

```css
.corpo {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 200px 15px 30px 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
.bloco {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 15px 5% 15px 5%;
    width: 300px;
    height: 350px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: grey;
}
.cabecalho-bloco {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: grey;
}
input[type="file"] {
    display: none;
}
#file {
    font-weight: normal;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 1px;
    color: grey;
    padding: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}
#file:hover {
    color: black;
}
```

```html
    <div class="corpo"> <!-- Blocos -->
        <div class="bloco">
            <div class="cabecalho-bloco"><h3 style="font-weight: bold;">Contagem</h3></div>
            <div>
             <form>
              <br><br>
              <a><label id="file" for="selecao-arquivo">Selecionar arquivo</label>
        <input id="selecao-arquivo" type="file"></a>
        <br><br>
        <input type="button" value="Baixar">
             </form>
            </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="bloco">
            <div class="cabecalho-bloco"><h3 style="font-weight: bold;">Promoção</h3></div>
            <div>
             <form>
              <br><br>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Produto">
              <br><br>
              <input type="button" value="Consultar">
             </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- Fim blocos -->
```

Comment: display: flex helps u check this [FiddleHere](https://jsfiddle.net/x24k74sk/)

Answer (score 1):

The default vertical alignment is `vertical-align: baseline`, so the browsers align the baselines of the blocks. In this case, the label of the first one with the input of the second one.
So the solution is to add `vertical-align: top` to the blocks.

```css
.corpo {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 200px 15px 30px 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.bloco {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 15px 5% 15px 5%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 350px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: grey;
  vertical-align:top;                   /* added */
}

.cabecalho-bloco {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: grey;
}

input[type="file"] {
  display: none;
}

#file {
  font-weight: normal;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 1px;
  color: grey;
  padding: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

#file:hover {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="corpo">
  <!-- Blocos -->
  <div class="bloco">
    <div class="cabecalho-bloco">
      <h3 style="font-weight: bold;">Contagem</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
      <form>
        <br><br>
        <label id="file" for="selecao-arquivo">Selecionar arquivo</label>
                <input id="selecao-arquivo" type="file">
        <br><br>
        <input type="button" value="Baixar">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bloco">
    <div class="cabecalho-bloco">
      <h3 style="font-weight: bold;">Promoção</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
      <form>
        <br><br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Produto">
        <br><br>
        <input type="button" value="Consultar">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> <!-- Fim blocos -->
```

I also took the liberty of removing the `<a>`..`</a>` from around the label, which did not serve any purpose whatsoever.

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry i did'nt set up a jsfiddle, but i did'nt know how to, i'm new around here.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="bloco1">    </div>  
<div class="bloco2">
</div>
```

use bootstrap column

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 bloco1"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 bloco2"></div>
  </div>
```

you can use many devices

Comment: Bootstrap is **massive** overkill for this.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use `<br>` to offset, that's just nasty and asking for problems. The reason for why I'm saying that is because all different web browsers use their own witch magic to work out how many vertical pixels that is.

The solution to your question:
In the `.bloco` class, add a `float:left;` parameter.

And next time you make this kind of question, please set up a jsfiddle.

Comment: Better than a fiddle, use StackOverflow snippet... the `<>` button in the editor. That way we don't need to leave the site to see an example.

Comment: Sorry guys, i did'nt know how to do it. Thank you for helping anyway!

Comment: @MatheusStiehler If one of the answers works for you, could you mark it as the solution by clicking on the check mark to the left? That way, the question will no longer show up under unanswered ones.

Answer (score 0):

Display flex help's u

```
 .corpo{
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 height: 400px;
 margin:200px 15px 30px 15px;
 text-align: center;
 display:flex;
  }
  .bloco{
 flex:1;
 display: inline-block;
 margin:15px 5% 15px 5%;
 width:300px;
 height: 350px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 3px;
 border-color: grey;
  }
```

[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/x24k74sk/)

Comment: Flex is not an option if you need to support IE 9 or earlier : http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox